# AMPScript does not modify the template while trigger send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have put the AMPScript in the template. After that I am triggering email programmatically. I am receiving the email, but without the data from AMPScript.

I am passing the attribute while sending an email. The data will be stored in Data extension. But it does not print in the template.

```
%%[
    SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
    SET @FromEmail = Lookup("TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231", "FromEmail", "First Name", @FirstName)
    IF EMPTY (@FromEmail) THEN 
        SET @FromEmail= 'Not able to lookup FromEmail' 
    ENDIF
    SET @FromName= Lookup("TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231", "FromName", "First Name", @FirstName)
    IF EMPTY (@FromName) THEN 
        SET @FromName= 'Not able to lookup FromName' 
    ENDIF
```

]%%

```
<p>
   %%=v(@FromEmail)=%%
   %%=v(@FromName)=%%
</p>
```

What could be the issue? How to resolve the same?

Comment: Is triggersend DE is Sendable?

Comment: Yes. It is Sendable.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue. Whenever we modify the template, we should publish changes to Triggered Sends

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Please post this as an answer to your question so anyone else having this trouble can easily find the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Gortonington I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with the below steps:

a) Suppose you have modify a template (Content tab + Click on My Templates) and

b) Update the Email (Content tab + my emails + Select the check box next to the email you wish to update + Click Properties +Click Apply Template Change + Click Save)

Then do a trigger send an email then the template which you have just updated does not reflect the changes which you have done.

c) So how to resolve this issue?

1. In your Salesforce Marketing Cloud app, click the Email Studio icon. Select Email.
2. Click the **Interactions** tab.
3. Click **Triggered Emails**.
4. The **Triggered Sends** screen appears.
5. Select the check box next to the Trigger sends.
6. Click on **Pause**
7. Click on **Publish Changes**
8. Click on **Start/Restart**

Now you run your program. You will receive the email with updated template.

**Note** : You should do the steps in the order a,b and then c